# log4j Database Appender does not work properly

Tags: java, logging, log4j

My log4j.properties file look like

```
log4j.rootLogger = ERROR,sql, Appender1

log4j.logger.com.endeca=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.endeca.itl.web.metrics=ERROR

log4j.appender.sql=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.sql.URL=jdbc:mysql://192.168.70.39:3306/cortex_mcss_ip
log4j.appender.sql.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.sql.user=root
log4j.appender.sql.password=123456
log4j.appender.sql.sql=INSERT INTO errorlog(Level,Msg,CreatedDate) VALUES ('%p','%m',now())
log4j.appender.sql.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout


log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=D:/Logs/Log4jWebDemo.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

when error occurs it works fine on console and file appender,but does not insert into databse anything ?

Note : databse parameters are 100% accurate in every corner.

Any one please help me to solve this...plz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly address your question:
you should debug this appender to see what happens.

1. Make sure that DB driver (mysql in this case) appears in the classpath of the application.
2. Make sure that the table / schema exist, because this appender by its own does not create a schema for you
3. Note that it has a "bufferSize" parameter, so only if the non-stored message count exceeds the buffer, the actual DB request gets performed.
4. Place a breakpoint on `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender#execute` and see how it really executes

Overall observation/side notes, not directly related to your answer but still can be valuable.
This appender is really outdated and is not a really good solution for modern production applications (unless you have a very small number of logs).

This appender doesn't use batch inserts supported by probably all modern RDBMSs.
This appender doesn't use prepared statements.

All-in-all storing logs in RDBMS doesn't really make sense nowadays, logs are meant to be read and analyzed, and RDBMS doesn't offer really handy tools for this (both visual and from the maintenance standpoint: how do delete obsolete messages? Bulk DELETE is very expensive, partitioning? Retention Policies for records are not really supported in many RDBMSs...

So, a much more modern approach is using tools like ElasticSearch + Kibana (+ some log shipper) or even streaming logs to the cloud (like Logz.io)